# Dispatch redux action from a window event listener

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am following the container/ui_component pattern to pass redux dispatch actions to my ui_component from the parent container. I can successfully call the dispatch actions from within the render method of the ui_component, for example, the onClick event below is working just fine.

My problem is I can't fire the same actions from an eventListener (handleResize) within the same component.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import classNames from 'classnames';


class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.updateDashVis.bind(this); // not sure if this is doing anything
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };


  handleResize() { 
    this.props.updateDashVis('app-dash'); // returns undefined
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     this.props.resetMe();
  }



  render() {
      return (

        // ...
        <div className="top-bar">

          <div className="burger" onClick={()=> {this.props.updateDashVis(this.props.appDashVis)}} ><i className="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          {/* onClick works fine and action is fired  */}

        </div>

        // ...


      );
  }
}

export default Dashboard
```

This is my First React/Redux/ES6 project, so this could be something simple. Any guidance would be welcome.

Comment: meant to say, "window event listener", not widow. There is a joke in there somewhere...

Comment: Figured it out. I created a new action that does not need an argument and then just bound it to the event handler:

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.props.hideDash);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.props.hideDash);
  }

Comment: Consider answering your own question and marking it as answered. That way others may benefit from your solution!

Answer (score 0):

method '`updateDashVis`' is passed via props which doesn't need any binding at constructor but you should bind 'this' reference to `handleResize` method in a constructor. So your constructor would like below...

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.handleResize = this.handleResize.bind(this);
```

}